# Grouping Tweens in Timeline GSAP

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

I have asked the same question on the GSAP forum but it's not an active forum as here, I guess. I do have some struggles on GSAP, I want to group the tweens in the timeline, rather than going individually, first two goes at the same time and then the second two and so on... I really try to figure out by myself, I add a minus delay but it's not working properly with ScrollMagic or I can't make it work. Here is my code:

```
let controllerPerspectiveFirst = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
perspectiveTimeline = new TimelineMax();

perspectiveTimeline
    .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--01', .4, { autoAlpha: .72, scaleY: .8, scaleX: .8, ease: Power4.easeOut } )
    .from( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--02', .4, { scaleY: 1.4, scaleX: 1.4, autoAlpha: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut } )
    .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--01', .4, { autoAlpha: 0, scaleY: 0, scaleX: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut } )
    .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--02', .4, { width: '180vw', scaleY: .6, scaleX: .6, ease: Power4.easeOut } )
    .from( '#as-perspective-bg--desert', .4, { scaleY: 1.4, scaleX: 1.4, autoAlpha: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut } );
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the amazing documentation of GreenSock, I have found the solution. I just add a position parameter ( https://greensock.com/position-parameter ) at the end of each tween. At the end:

```
let controllerPerspectiveFirst = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    perspectiveTimeline = new TimelineMax();

    perspectiveTimeline
        .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--01', .4, { autoAlpha: .72, scaleY: .8, scaleX: .8, ease: Power4.easeOut }, 0 )
        .from( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--02', { scaleY: 1.4, scaleX: 1.4, autoAlpha: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut }, 0 )
        .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--01', .4, { autoAlpha: 0, scaleY: 0, scaleX: 0, x: '-40vw', y: '-70vh', ease: Power4.easeOut }, 1 )
        .to( '#as-perspective-bg--mountain--02', .4, { width: '180vw', scaleY: .6, scaleX: .6, x: '-40vw', y: '-28vw', ease: Power4.easeOut }, 1 )
        .from( '#as-perspective-bg--desert', .4, { scaleY: 1.4, scaleX: 1.4, autoAlpha: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut }, 1 );
```